# How to make scalajs project depend on a subproject?

Tags: scala, scala.js

I use a case class from a sub project and receive error: `Referring to non-existent` at runtime

In build.sbt, I have:

```
lazy val scalaJsProject = (project in file("scala-project/"))
  .dependsOn(modelProject)
```

I guess `dependsOn` does not work for scalaJs?

Comment: modelProject is scalajs project or regular scala project?

Comment: Yeah, that's usually the key question -- a Scala.js project can't depend on an ordinary JVM project.  If you need to share models between the two sides, you need to use the CrossProject mechanism, to define a project that get compiled both ways...

Comment: @tkachuko modelProject is a regular scala project. I will take a look at using CrossProject mechanism as Justin du Coeur suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed instruction here https://github.com/scala-js/scalajs-cross-compile-example to create crossProject. And put all models into shared folder of crossProject. And it recoginizes both in JVM and JS project.